# How to make any number entered into a jTextField appear in x's?

Tags: java, swing, passwords

I made a GUI where a user enters a pin and hits enter. However the jTextField displays the actual numbers entered by the user and I'm trying to make it appear in x's but not able to do so. any help would be appreciated and if you can suggest anything :)

I tried this code for the text field but its wrong lol
    jTextField.setText("xxxx");

this is the code for one of the buttons code

```
if(evt.getSource() == buttonOne){
            if(jTextField.getText().length() < 4){
                if(clearField == 1){
                    jTextField.setText("0");
                    clearField = 0;
                } else{
                    jTextField.setText(jTextField.getText() + "1");
                }
            }
}
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a [JPasswordField](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JPasswordField.html) instead of a `JTextField`. This is designed to hide the entered text.

Comment: I have changed the JTextField to JPassword but pin numbers still show...... is there something i need to add? thanks

Comment: @MOHAMEDAHMED When I've used a `JPasswordField` it has just worked, and according to the API it should just work. I can't tell from here why it would not be working for you.

Comment: ah thanks for the help tho i will work wwith this until I see the problem @khelwood